# Opening Sublime Text from Git Bash now requires the IDE to be already open

Tags: git, bash, sublimetext3

I've been using sublime from git bash for almost a year now, but after updating to the most recent git it appears something might have changed.

Uptil now I've been using the sublime alias with no issues:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

and it showing up in .gitconfig as:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = D:\\My Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
    editor = subl -n -w
```

Where the flags `-n` is for a new window and `-w` is for waiting for the result.

I couldn't find any reference why this would stop working, and it works as long as sublime is already open, and if it isn't no error is shown it just shows a empty prompt ready for the next command.  Any ideas?

The [docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) don't appear to have changed much in the last year so I'm not sure why this would have stopped opening an new sublime text instance.

```
Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories
   or: subl [arguments] -               edit stdin

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -s or --stay:        Keep the application activated after closing the file
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

--wait is implied if reading from stdin. Use --stay to not switch back
to the terminal when a file is closed (only relevant if waiting for a file).
```

Similarly, Git doesn't appear to have changed the way they add an editor to [git config](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Basic-Client-Configuration).

Comment: If you run `subl -n -w` from the git bash shell directly without sublime running what happens?

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner it pauses for about 2 or 3 seconds (has a think) then jumps down to an empty prompt.  If it is open it and I omit -w it opens places me in sublime in an new file

Comment: "[P]laces [you] in sublime"? In a new window or in the git bash shell window? Does sublime have a verbose flag or a log file?

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner as I mentioned in the question there's no errors.  When sublime isn't open `subl -n -w` pauses then jumps to new prompt, `subl -n` does the same.  When sublime is open `subl -n -w` opens an empty new file and places focus on it and waits to be closed before jumping to new empty prompt, the same for `subl -n` but with no waiting.  The last two are what is expected, and has been working before updating Git (which is the only change of note in the last week on my dev box).  Checking for verbose flag and log file now.

Comment: What is `subl` mapped to? An alias pointing to `sublime_text.exe`, or to the `subl.exe` command line utility itself? Also, what build of Sublime are you running?

Comment: Hi @MattDMo, I've set my environment variables to point to the folder where I've installed sublime text 3 (build 3083) so `subl` is using `subl.exe` the command line utility

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question?

Comment: Technically this isn't a programming question and so it probably belongs on Super User instead of here. That might be why.

Comment: You said what happens when *git* launches it. I asked what happens when *you* do manually. It could act differently in that case (git could be discarding error output or running it in a slightly different environment). Did sublime update when this started happening or just git?

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner, that description was manually opening sublime using Git bash using those commands, but just in case I tried the Win command prompt as well with the same effect.  Sorry if I don't understand what you mean if that's still not what you meant.  Apparently, Sublime build 3083 hasn't updated their stable build since March 2015 so Sublime hasn't changed.  Sorry, am I able to transfer this to SuperUser?

Comment: @mtpultz This question is perfectly on-topic here. Sublime is a tool used primarily for programming, so questions like this are fine here. People wouldn't be complaining if it was about `vim` or `emacs`...

Comment: @EtanReisner From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), software questions are allowed if if they cover "*[...] software tools commonly used by programmers*". Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, Notepad++, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext3+or+sublimetext+or+vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+notepad%2b%2b) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: Wasn't my vote and you'll notice I was helping. I was merely speculating as to why someone *might* have voted that way. And I wouldn't, at all, be surprised if people looked slightly side-ways at a question about configuring vim to play tetris or getting emacs set up for latex so you can write your book on poetry. (Since, after all, the end to your quoted bit is _"[...] a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_.) Whether they should or not is a different question entirely.

Comment: As to the actual question here I can't think of what the git update could have done to change this. This issue is, as far as I can imagine, entirely a sublime-internal communication problem. The "this is Windows" after all part of my brain is telling me to ask if you've restarted your computer since this started happening and seen if it continues? And then to ask if you've tried just reinstalling sublime and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner, I tried a new install of an older build and a dev build, rebooted multiple times, but for now I think I'll just leave sublime open so my normal workflow isn't interrupted based on this change then wait it out or think up another solution in future that gets around it when I have more time.  Thanks again for the help